# Pause Audio in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a series of audio files that play based on eventListeners, but I cannot get the previous audio file to pause / stop whenever a new one is called. How can I implement this?

Here's my code:

```
    Narrator.greeting = function(){
        let greeting = new Audio('greeting.wav');
        greeting.play()
        return greeting
    }
        const greetingNarrator = document.querySelector('#greetingID').addEventListener('click', 
                                 Narrator.greeting); // Plays greeting audio
    
    Narrator.introduction = function(){
        greeting = Narrator.greeting()
        greeting.pause() // I have also tried :: greeting.play().then(() => {greeting.pause()})
        let introduction = new Audio('introduction.wav')
        introduction.play()
    }
        const introductionNarrator = document.querySelector('#introID').addEventListener('click', 
                                     Narrator.introduction); // Plays intro audio, but overlaps greeting audio and spits error
```

Whenever I call to 'pause()' any audio file that is playing, I catch the following error:

```
DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()
```

How can I pause the audio that's playing before playing the next one? Thanks!

Comment: This code seems somewhat convoluted, but it's not a [mcve] because it's missing some of the code necessary to make it work, so it's hard to offer a complete answer. There's probably a more elegant way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve, so if you don't mind [adding more context and details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), I can probably offer a better approach.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the reply! I basically have some audio assets that need to play during certain page navigation events, ie. the user clicks their way through a certain part of the website and audio assets play accordingly - but I don't want the audio to overlap if someone clicks on the next link while the previous audio asset is still playing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the details. Looking at it again, `greeting = Narrator.greeting(); greeting.pause()` seems rather strange -- this says "trigger playing the greeting, but then pause it right away". What's the point of these two lines? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225731/6243352) is the behavior you want? (see the bottom snippet, there are two buttons that pause the other one when clicked). If you want multiple audio to play one after the other, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69305053/6243352).

Comment: Here's a full playlist that combines both techniques, only one thing playing at once and continuous play: https://ggorlen.github.io/amplified-gravel/